# Regex for more than one word separated by space?

Tags: regex

I need a regex for 2 or more words separated by space, eg:

```
Test            //invalid
Test two        //valid
Test two three  //valid
Test-two        //invalid
```

[\w\s]+   gives me all the words, but not sure how to exclude 1 word from validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't include the spaces in the character class:  `\w+\s+\w+`

By leaving the spaces in the character class, you've specified that you want any number of word character *or* spaces, which will quickly gobble up the whole string.  By separating the word and space classes, you specify that you want "any number of word characters followed by any number of space characters, then some more word characters".

Unless you're looking to capture the words, remove the quantifier from them as you don't care how long the words are, merely that they are present: `\w\s+\w`

Comment: "one two three" doesn't validate,  three is looking for another word

Comment: [Works just fine for me](https://regex101.com/r/eS9iC3/1).  The pattern will match between the "one" and "two" and the string will be validated.

Comment: Doesn't validate more than 2 words

Comment: @che-azeh: correct, but it wouldn't be hard to modify.  Specifically, extracting `\s+\w+` into a repeatable pattern would do the trick: `\w+(?:\s+\w+)+`

Answer (score 1):

word class, space, word class...

`\w+ \w+`

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but for future views

```
/(\w+\s+[^-])+\S[^-]+/
```

This regex will return valid ones and the first valid part of the invalid inputs.